# Rails 4 - jQuery not replacing html

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application working with two models Gallery and Photo, with each photo belonging to a gallery and gallery having many photos. Everything works correctly except the jQuery uploads. The photos are being uploaded to the gallery however I have to refresh the page in order to see the updates. However, when I check the response code I can see the the update is made on the server end.

PhotosController

```
def create
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:photo][:gallery_id])
    if params[:images]
        params[:images].each do |image|
            @gallery.photos.create(image: image)
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to @gallery }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
end
```

GalleriesController

```
def show
    @photo = Photo.new
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.js
    end
end
```

/photos/create.js.erb

```
$("#photos").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'shared/photo', locals: {photo: @photo}) %>");
```

/view/galleries/_photos.html.erb

```
<div id="photos" class="row">
    <% @gallery.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= render partial: 'shared/photo', locals: {photo: photo} %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

/view/shared/_photo_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@photo, :remote => true, :html => { multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <%= token_tag(nil) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id, value: @gallery.id %>
    <%= f.label :image, "Upload images:" %>
    <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Photo", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

console.log

```
Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-01 20:34:13 -0400
Processing by PhotosController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p3FpgJeHOnqjIKK8I+0WNKv4x7JPqkvdmBPzD9XHmj0=", "photo"=>{"gallery_id"=>"8"}, "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010594bfa0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y_/s9cr1w213wgg68x_3n64gxy800011c/T/RackMultipart20140501-65824-1kr4fcr>, @original_filename="IMAG0376.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"IMAG0376.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Gallery Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "gallery_id", "image", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 02 May 2014 00:34:14 UTC +00:00], ["gallery_id", 8], ["image", "IMAG0376.jpg"], ["updated_at", Fri, 02 May 2014 00:34:14 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/galleries/8
Completed 302 Found in 1802ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Started GET "/galleries/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-01 20:34:15 -0400
Processing by GalleriesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  Gallery Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
  Photo Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."gallery_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["gallery_id", 8]]
  Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."gallery_id" = $1  [["gallery_id", 8]]
  Rendered shared/_photo.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_photo.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered galleries/_photos.html.erb (9.1ms)
  Rendered galleries/_photo_form.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered galleries/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 98.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

Comment: If you put `console.log('here');` as the first line of your create.js.erb file, does it log correctly in the browser? The first thing you want to determine is whether that JS view is even rendering.

Comment: Your ```/photos/create.js.erb``` response is going to replace the contents of ```#photos``` with only a single photo. Is this the desired action?

Comment: updated with console log. I don't think create.js.erb is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues. One with the respond_to block and the other with @photo variable.

create.js.erb expects a @photo variable and one was not being passed by the create controller. Editing the create controller as follows resolves the issue.

```
def create
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:photo][:gallery_id])
    if params[:images]
        params[:images].each do |image|
        @gallery.photos.create(image: image)
            @gallery.photos.each do |photo|
                @photo = Photo.find(photo.id)
            end
        end
    end
end
```